# Possible CORS or proxy issues when fetching Strapi data on a Nginx/VPS server?

Tags: nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy, strapi, vps

I am using Strapi on the backend and hosting it on my VPS server running Nginx. I have reactJS on the front, when I run the front end on my local machine it fetches the data from Strapi perfectly.
However after deploying to Hostinger I am running into issues fetching the data from strapi, I am not sure so far if it's a CORS issue or if it's a proxy issue.
I am doing this for the first time as a newbie, never used Nginx or a VPS as a host for my backend before either. I followed a tutorial a few weeks ago and I am trying to create it on my own this time.
I also noticed in the network tab that the request URL gets changed from http:// into https:// instead of http (which works on the local machine)

appreciate if someone could point me to what I might be missing here
[image: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api]
[image: /var/www/api/config/middleware.js-][image: /var/www/api/config/server.js-]

I tried to change the CORS settings in the middleware.js file and added both the domain address with http and https in the origin array but nothing happened.
Also I am not sure if it makes sense that both Nginx and strapi should listen on the same port, I tried to change it into port 1337 because that's the default with Strapi but it didn't work out.
my understanding that the Nginx server would listen on port 80 and through reverse proxying Strapi will be able to get the request on port 1337 but that didn't help either

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you get CORS error because you can’t query http from https

I’ve would recommend reading this:
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/nginx-proxy

This would give you a really good start on how to configure nginx and strapi.

But before that:

1. Get yourself a domain, configure DNS.
2. Acquire SSL certificate with acme.sh or certbot.
   *there plenty of video tutorials online google for `nginx acme.sh`*

Then you likely get it going…